# Remove public from url on google cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded a laravel project on google cloud after creating a VM.
The main problem is there is public attached with url. without public the url is not working.

I tried by htaccess file like I have done on shared hosting. But on the VM it is not working and also I want to remove the public without changing the htaccess. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Apache or Nginx ?

Comment: This is apache.

Comment: do you have your-site.conf available in sites-available ? or 000-default.conf ?

Comment: great, I will delete my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer:

I have changed the file:

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

 DocumentRoot /var/www/html from 

 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video_uploading/public
```

then I have updated my file:

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find the following code inside the editor:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change to:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that restart the Apache server via:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```